# Crocodoc document font size is too small on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, font-size, crocodoc

I'm trying to use [Crocodoc](http://crocodoc.com) to view documents on my site. The documents look good on desktop but their scaling algorithm is too severe leading to the font-size being too small on mobile. As an example, see this link and re-size the browser or check on your phone: https://crocodoc.com/view/92GF0fI39qf4YlCK18njk7LOaz6qtCuVVFQU5T1TbK-HARw_oJutfq7clutH5rYCEoV85rk9a05kdE-du4A9LdEaNIW0cORvFuQHlQ

**update** to include permanent link since session links expire after an hour:https://crocodoc.com/see-it-in-action/

The font-size goes from ~`10em` to ~`3em` as you shrink from ~`960px` width to ~`320px` width. `3em` is too small to view on any device without zooming in which is annoying because then the document doesn't fit on the screen.

I'm not seeing a simple fix and am wondering if anyone hacked around with Crocodoc to know how to deal with this UX issue?

Comment: What is the outcome you would like? Stop shrinking the text beyond a certain size? Even if the document looks wrong and out of proportion?

Comment: -@MoinZaman the outcome i'd like is to be able to read the text. I think the images and other elements could look somewhat wrong as long as one didn't have to squint so much (or zoom in) to read the text.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a slight misunderstanding here.  Crocodoc does not scale text based on the size of the display.  Rather, when a document is first viewed an effort is made to scale the entire page/document to optimally appear on the screen.  Crocodoc documents are meant to be pixel-perfect renderings of the original document, rather than reflowed text like you would see with an e-reader.  When you zoom in and out the scale of the entire document will change accordingly, just as it would in Preview, etc.  Does that clear things up?

By the way, your link will no longer work since document viewing sessions expire after 1 hour.

Comment: -@Bennett, thanks i understand all this. I was wondering if anyone had attempted to modify the crocodoc JS/CSS to reflow the document on different devices (e.g., CSS media queries, etc.).

Comment: Hey Tim. I've also has issues with Crocodocs on mobile. The best you can do with CSS (when using JS API) seems to change behaviour of #DocViewer and .doc styles. Then, it's all about modifying CSS within the document by Javascript when the doc has loaded. I haven't been able to find solutions to text wrapping / or doc optimum scaling this way thought... What's sure, is that the JS API gives you more advanced embedding capabilities.